# WPF - combobox items is getting duplicated

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm creating WPF application and in my settings panel I have couple of labels, textboxes, comboboxes and two buttons (Save) and (Cancel).

Xaml

```
<ComboBox x:Name="myCombobox" Grid.Column="1" Margin="18,372,4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" SelectionChanged="MyCombobox_SelectionChanged" />
```

I already have added items to my combobox :

```
myCombobox.Items.Add("Test1");
myCombobox.Items.Add("Test2");
myCombobox.Items.Add("Test3");
foreach (var item in myCombobox.Items)
    if (item.Equals(Properties.Settings.Default.MyCombobox))
        myCombobox.SelectedItem = item;
```

and added SelectionChanged event. This is how it looks:

```
private void MyCombobox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (myCombobox.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals("Test1"))
    {
        testGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else if (myCombobox.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals("Test2") || myCombobox.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals("Test3"))
    {
        testGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

When I click the Cancel button and restart my settings panel the items of my combobox are duplicated. (Same values twice).

I have tried to prevent this by adding to Cancel buttons click event

```
myCombobox.Items.Clear();
```

but at this point another problem exists (myCombobox.SelectedItem is null) and I get this error:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   IdentificationStation.exe but was not handled in user code

How could I prevent comboboxes items to be duplicated? Or should I do the `MyCombobox_SelectionChanged` otherwice , any helps?

Comment: myCombobox.Items.Clear(); add this in onchange event.

Comment: How you are populating your combo? The code relevant to the question should be added.

Comment: The app is definitely calling the 'myComboBox.Items.Add(...)' twice in the routine. Where/how is this called? can you show the method that has this calls?

Comment: Please add the xaml where the combobox is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just avoid

> 'System.NullReferenceException'

by testing if `myCombobox.SelectedItem` is null on `MyCombobox_SelectionChanged`?

```
private void MyCombobox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (myCombobox.SelectedItem != null)
        if (myCombobox.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals("Test1"))
        {
            testGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else if (myCombobox.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals("Test2") || myCombobox.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals("Test3"))
        {
            testGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think it's bad manner to do it like that.

Answer (score -2):

Use this check to stop addition of duplicate items:

```
if(!myComboBox.Items.Contains("item"))
{
    myComboBox.Items.Add("item");
}
```

Comment: you only want to have these type of validation if the combobox is updated dynamically. For static updates like above, the coder should be able to see the call stack and fix the routine so that it doesn't get called twice.